# XML search by tag text using python

Tags: python, xml

Here is my code and XML:

```
xml_string = """
<data>
    <user>
        <name>123</name>
    </user>
    <user>
        <name>456</name>
    </user>
</data>
"""

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring(xml_string)
```

I'm trying to find `<user>` tag where `<name>` has text value equal to 123.

What I have tried:

```
result = root.findall("./user[name = '123']")
result = root.findall("./user[./name = '123']")
result = root.findall("./user[/name = '123']")
result = root.findall("./user[./name text() = '123']")
```

None of these attempts worked. What am I missing?

Error I'm getting:

```
raise SyntaxError("invalid predicate") 
File "<string>", line None
SyntaxError: invalid predicate
```

Comment: Maybe regex could work?

Comment: If this is what you're trying to find `<name>123</name>`, regex will do the job.

Comment: @JoeR that's exactly the opposite of the advice you should give; regex is *not* the best way to parse XML, which is *not* a regular language, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, I agree and I would never suggest to parse HTML or XML using regex, however, if the OP just trying to find this one thing `<name>123</name>` that's an other story.

Comment: @JoeR but that isn't what the OP wants, they're after the `user` tag *containing* that.

Comment: As agmangas pointed out, the syntax is invalid. Supported selectors and their syntax can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#example as well as some examples.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am not sure if the OP is trying to find the `<user>` tag or he is really after the `<name>123</name>`, in any case, that's why I mentioned it in the comments and not posted an regex answer, because I wasn't sure what the OP is looking for exactly.

Comment: *"I'm trying to find <user> tag where <name> has text value equal to 123."*

Comment: @jonrsharpe In any case, it seems that the user's name is the important data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the exception says, it seems you have a syntax error in the predicate, there shouldn't be a space between the tag name and the value:

```
xml_string = """
<data>
    <user>
        <name>123</name>
    </user>
    <user>
        <name>456</name>
    </user>
</data>
"""

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring(xml_string)

result = root.findall("./user[name='123']")

print result
```

Comment: That's the thing! Thanks